# Accessing View on Dispatchers.IO on coroutine does not crash the app, why ? But UI can only be accessed via MAIN Thread in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Here is the code I am using :

```
 (application as TestApp).applicationScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {

        println("Thread 2 "+Thread.currentThread().name)
        binding.username.setText("text2")

    }

    (application as TestApp).applicationScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {

        println("Thread 3 "+Thread.currentThread().name)
        binding.username.setText("text3")

    }
```

Here I am accessing the TextView on Dispatchers.IO and Dispatchers.Default thread from an Activity, which is not a main thread. Still the app runs properly and does not throw any exception.

The printed thread names are :

```
 Thread 3 DefaultDispatcher-worker-4

 Thread 2 DefaultDispatcher-worker-2
```

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

It throws for me (using `lifecycleScope` in a `Fragment`):

`CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

What's your output for those `println` statements, are the thread names different? What thread are you inflating `binding` on?

It's possible that under the hood, in your particular environment, those coroutines aren't being executed on different threads. Like when I run it, both the `IO` and `Default` dispatchers end up printing a thread name beginning with `Defaultdispatcher-worker-` which implies they're starting with the `Default` dispatcher's thread pool. And there's such a thing as an [*unconfined dispatcher*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher):

> **The Dispatchers.Unconfined coroutine dispatcher starts a coroutine in the caller thread, but only until the first suspension point**. After suspension it resumes the coroutine in the thread that is fully determined by the suspending function that was invoked.

Since your coroutines don't suspend (e.g. with `delay`) it would be possible that they'd hit the UI updates before execution is moved to another thread. Like it says there, `Dispatchers.Unconfined` is an edge-case dispatcher not recommended for use in general, but it's *possible* that something like that is happening behind the scenes for you, handling the dispatch more efficiently. (Not for me though!) You could try adding a `delay` to each before the UI touching, and see if it changes anything

(I don't know much at all about the underlying management of coroutines, I could be completely off base. I'm just pointing this out as a possible line of investigation since you're seeing weird behaviour!)

Comment: I checked by putting delay , yet no exception and the TextField is also updated by the text. 
I am using application global scope to launch the coroutines

The thread names printed are :
    *System.out: Thread 3 DefaultDispatcher-worker-4*
    *System.out: Thread 2 DefaultDispatcher-worker-2*